# Saving the result of grid.draw to a ggplot object

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need assistance in saving the results of `grid.draw` to a ggplot graph object.

I can save the results of amending my ggplot with `grid.draw` by using the following

```
savepdf("H:\\plot name", width = 36, height = 28)
gt <- ggplotGrob(plot1)
gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"
grid.draw(gt)

dev.off()

# plot1 is the ggplot object that was amended as follows

 plot1 = plot1 + annotation_custom(grob = textGrob("my text", gp=gpar(fontsize=15)),  
                          xmin = this.much, 
                          xmax = this.much, 
                          ymin = -that.much, 
                          ymax = -that.much )
```

This enables me to put text below x axis labels.

I have a series of these graphs that I would like to save in a grid of graphs 
but do not want to resort to `par(mfrow())` as the new dimensions distort the final graph I need. I would like to use `multiplot(plot1, plot2,...., plotx)` and hence the changes due to `grid.draw` need to be embedded in the ggplot objects.

Multiplot is available here
http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/

Comment: Why not just use the new caption feature in ggplot2?

Comment: or `ggsave("file.pdf", arrangeGrob(grobs = lapply(letters[1:3], function(txt) arrangeGrob(ggplot(), bottom = txt))))`